# Finding the matrix of $L$ with respect to the following bases:

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $L:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ be the linear map:
>   $$L((x_1,x_2,x_3)^T)=(x_1-x_2+x_3,x_1-2x_2,x_2-3x_3,2x_1+x_3)^T$$
>   Find the matrix of $L$ with respect to the following bases: $\{(0,0,1)^T,(0,1,1)^T,(1,1,1)^T\}$ for$\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\{(0,1,0,0)^T,(1,1,0,0)^T,(0,0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1,1)^T\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^4$

**My try:**

Given $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x_1-x_2+x_3 \\ x_1-2x_2 \\ x_2-3x_3 \\ 2x_1+x_3 \end{bmatrix}=x_1\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}+x_2\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+x_3\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

After this I have no idea what to do. Can anyone please explain how to proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give names to the bases-you have a basis $B=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and a basis $C=(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)$ in $\mathbb{R^4}$. By definition, the columns of the transformation matrix with respect to these bases are the coordinates of the vectors $L(e_1),L(e_2),L(e_3)$ with respect to the basis C. So calculate the vectors $L(e_1),L(e_2),L(e_3)$ and then calculate their coordinates in the basis C. That's simply solving systems of linear equations-might be annoying but not hard.

Comment: So, I just need to plug in $e_1,e_2,e_3$ in $L(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$ right?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the transformation $L$ on each of the vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3$. In the basis you wrote you have $e_1=(0,0,1)$, $e_2=(0,1,1)$, $e_3=(1,1,1)$. And as I wrote, you then need to calculate the coordinates of the vectors you get with respect to the basis in $\mathbb{R^4}$ that is given to you. (and not with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R^4}$)

Comment: So, when I plugged in $e_1,e_2,e_3$ in $L$ I got the matrix as $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -2 & -1 \\ -3 & -2 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$ is it correct

Comment: And how should I plug in $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ because there is no $x_4$ term in the given $L$

Comment: Ok, you calculated the vectors $L(e_1),L(e_2),L(e_3)$. Now you need to find their coordinates with respect to the basis $(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)$. Coordinates of $L(e_1)$ with respect to the basis are scalars $a,b,c,d$ such that $L(e_1)=af_1+bf_2+cf_3+df_4$. Find them and then $(a,b,c,d)^T$ will be the first column in your matrix. Then do the same for $L(e_2)$ and $L(e_3)$.

Comment: I'll give an example. You found that $L(e_1)=(1,0,−3,1)^T$. By solving linear equations you can see that $(1,0,-3,1)^T=-1*(0,1,0,0)^T+1*(1,1,0,0)^T-4*(0,0,1,0)^T+1*(0,0,1,1)^T$. Hence the coordinates of $L(e_1)$ are $(-1,1,-4,1)^T$, this is the first column of the matrix you need. Now do the same for $L(e_2)$,$L(e_3)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80953/discussion-between-philip-and-mark).

Comment: I didn't understand how you got those values as $(-1,1,-4,1)^T$

Comment: That's what I explained in the previous comment: coefficients of $L(e_1)$ with respect to the basis $(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)$ are scalars $a,b,c,d$ such that $L(e_1)=af_1+bf_2+cf_3+df_4$. There is a theorem that says these scalars exist and are unique. So for example, in your exercise we have $(1,0,-3,1)^T=(-1)*(0,1,0,0)^T+1*(1,1,0,0)^T+(-4)*(0,0,1,0)^T+1*(0,0,1,1)^T$, you can simply check that it's true. Hence we have $a=-1,b=1,c=-4,d=1$.